# App Engine Development Server CPU usage

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to measure or monitor how much of the server's CPU my app will be using for a particular task/query, etc? In many tutorials you see people talking about optimization, and that some operations are CPU 'expensive'. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python, I think that [AppStats](https://sites.google.com/site/appengineappstats/) can give you what you are looking for.